Как передавать данные о пользователе из Telegram при запуске WebApp приложения?
Пришла в голову идея написания игрового бота в Telegram с возможностью просмотра своего профиля в webapp приложении. Но столкнулся с проблемой: каким образом можно передавать данные о пользователе из Telegram при каждом запуске WebApp приложения. Это нужно, чтобы при каждом запуске человеку не приходилось входить в свой аккаунт(банальная сверка введенных данных и данных из бд), а чтобы при запуске webapp приложения производилась сверка его Telegram ID и сразу запускало в профиль(по аналогии работает такая игра как hamster combat). Само приложение будет написано на языке Python с использованием библиотеки Flet

Посмотрите этот вопрос, как указание направления.
